# How do you transfer a variable from one computer to another with PostMessage?

Tags: javascript, html

Messaging with Javascript can be done with `window.postMessage("yourMessage", "http://example.com")` but from what I've tested, you cant send variables over this. Am I doing it wrong, or am I using the wrong function? Here's my sender:

```
<html>
//This Page is http://example.com/2

<label>
    <textarea readonly></textarea>
</label>
<button onclick="messageFunction(x)">SEND MESSAGE</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function messageFunction(xsend) {
        window.postMessage((xsend), "http://example.com")
    }

    //Just some basic variable
    let x = "Whatever you want it to be"

</script>
</html>
```

And here's where I hit my problem(it might even be in the code above), if I were to say add a `window.addEventListener('message', function)` how would I be able to take out the variable?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)?   "The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it."

Comment: Can try using WebRTC. Or use websockets on a server

Comment: https://www.cybelesoft.com/blog/cross-domain-messages-using-javascript/?cn-reloaded=1